# Convert timestamp string into local time

Tags: c++, c, linux

How to convert timestamp string, e.g. "1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00" into UTC time. The result of conversion should be *timespec* structure as in [utimensat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html) input arguments.

```
// sorry, should be get_utc_time    
timespec get_local_time(const char* ts);
```

P.S. I need solution using either standard Linux/C/C++ facilities (whatever that means) or Boost C++ library.

Comment: Maybe `strptime`?

Comment: You are asking for the result to be local time, but also asking for the `timespec` to be as specified by [utimensat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html), which specifies UTC.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: "C/C++" doesn't mean very much at all.  Good answers for C++ will be quite different to good answers for C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumption:**  You want the `"+01:00"` to be subtracted from the `"1997-07-16T19:20:30.45"` to get a UTC timestamp and then convert that into a `timespec`.

Here is a C++20 solution that will automatically handle the centisecond precision *and* the [+/-]hh:mm UTC offset for you:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

std::timespec
get_local_time(const char* ts)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    istringstream in{ts};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    sys_time<nanoseconds> tp;
    in >> parse("%FT%T%Ez", tp);
    auto tps = floor<seconds>(tp);
    return {.tv_sec = tps.time_since_epoch().count(),
            .tv_nsec = (tp - tps).count()};
}
```

When used like this:

```
auto r = get_local_time("1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00");
std::cout << '{' << r.tv_sec << ", " << r.tv_nsec << "}\n";
```

The result is:

```
{869077230, 450000000}
```

- `std::chrono::parse` will subtract the `+/-hh:mm` UTC offset from the parsed local value to obtain a UTC timestamp (to up to nanosecond precision).
- If the input has precision seconds, this code will handle it.  If the precision is as fine as nanoseconds, this code will handle it.
- If the input does not conform to this syntax, an exception will be thrown.  If this is not desired, remove `in.exceptions(ios::failbit);`, and then you must check `in.fail()` to see if the parse failed.
- This code will also handle dates prior to the UTC epoch of 1970-01-01 by putting a negative value into `.tv_sec`, and a positive value ([0, 999'999'999]) into `.tv_nsec`.  Note that handling pre-epoch dates is normally outside of the `timespec` specification, and so most C utilities will not handle such a `timespec` value.
- If you can not use C++20, or if your vendor has yet to implement this part of C++20, there exists a header-only library which implements this part of C++20, and works with C++11/14/17.  I have not linked to it here as it is not in the set: "standard Linux/C/C++ facilities (whatever that means) or Boost C++ library".  I'm happy to add a link if requested.

Comment: @TobySpeight:  I purposefully used `<time.h>` over `<ctime>` because the OP requested/used `timespec` instead of `std::timespec`.

Comment: I just assumed that was because OP was confused about which language (C or C++) was being used!

Comment: Perhaps.  But `<time.h>`/`timespec` is just as correct as `<ctime>`/`std::timespec`.  Mixing the two, as we now have:  `<ctime>`/`timespec`, is incorrect.  Though I'm not aware of any platform that will diagnose that error.

Comment: Oh, I see I overlooked a bit.  My platform is one of those that puts the names in the global namespace - quite irritating for someone who likes to lean on the compiler to spot problems!  I've made it consistent now - though you're welcome to rollback if you think the C style version is better. I won't take offence!

Comment: Perhaps our conversation will be educational for others :-)

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, here's how you could do this in mostly-standard C.  It's somewhat cumbersome, because C's date/time support is still rather fragmented, unlike the much more complete support which C++ has, as illustrated in [Howard Hinnant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124550#74126140).  (Also, two of the functions I'm going to use are not specified by the C Standard, although they're present on many/most systems.)

If you have the semistandard `strptime` function, and if you *didn't* care about subseconds and explicit time zones, it would be relatively straightforward.  `strptime` is a (partial) inverse of `strftime`, parsing a time string under control of a format specifier, and constructing a `struct tm`.  Then you can call `mktime` to turn that `struct tm` into a `time_t`.  Then you can use the `time_t` to populate a `struct timespec`.

```
char *inpstr = "1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00";

struct tm tm;
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
char *p = strptime(inpstr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &tm);
if(p == NULL) {
    printf("strptime failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

tm.tm_isdst = -1;
time_t t = mktime(&tm);
if(t == -1) {
    printf("mktime failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

struct timespec ts;
ts.tv_sec = t;
ts.tv_nsec = 0;

printf("%ld %ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
printf("%s", ctime(&ts.tv_sec));
printf("rest = %s\n", p);
```

In my time zone, currently UTC+4, this prints

```
869095230 0
Wed Jul 16 19:20:30 1997
rest = .45+01:00
```

But you did have subsecond information, and you did have an explicit time zone, and there's no built-in support for those in any of the basic C time-conversion functions, so you have to do things "by hand".  Here's one way to do it.  I'm going to use `sscanf` to separate out the year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and other components.  I'm going to use those components to populate a `struct tm`, then use the semistandard `timegm` function to convert them straight to a UTC time.  (That is, I temporarily assume that the HH:MM:SS part was UTC.)  Then I'm going to manually correct for the time zone.  Finally, I'm going to populate the `tv_nsec` field of the `struct timesec` with the subsecond information I extracted back in the beginning.

```
int y, m, d;
int H, M, S;
int ss;     /* subsec */
char zs;    /* zone sign */
int zh, zm; /* zone hours, minutes */
int r = sscanf(inpstr, "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d.%2d%c%d:%d",
            &y, &m, &d, &H, &M, &S, &ss, &zs, &zh, &zm);
if(r != 10 || (zs != '+' && zs != '-')) {
    printf("parse failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

struct tm tm;
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
tm.tm_year = y - 1900;
tm.tm_mon = m - 1;
tm.tm_mday = d;
tm.tm_hour = H;
tm.tm_min = M;
tm.tm_sec = S;
time_t t = timegm(&tm);

if(t == -1) {
    printf("timegm failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

long int z = ((zh * 60L) + zm) * 60;

if(zs == '+')    /* East of Greenwich */
     t -= z;
else t += z;

struct timespec ts;
ts.tv_sec = t;
ts.tv_nsec = ss * (1000000000 / 100);

printf("%ld %ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
printf("%s", ctime(&ts.tv_sec));
printf(".%02ld\n", ts.tv_nsec / (1000000000 / 100));
```

For me this prints

```
869077230 450000000
Wed Jul 16 14:20:30 1997
.45
```

The time zone and subsecond information have been honored.

This code makes no special provision for dates prior to 1970.  I think it will work if `mktime`/`timegm` work.

As mentioned, two of these functions — `strptime` and `timegm` — are not specified by the ANSI/ISO C Standard and are therefore not guaranteed to be available everywhere.